# Use Windows 7 classic theme but keep features like peek?

Tags: windows-7, themes, aero

Is there a way to enable aero peek on the Windows 7 classic theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, theres no way at all. Windows Classic uses a different graphics engine than aero.**

Just some of my own commentary, and from my own experience, aero and basic/classic aren't too different fps wise. I would advise to stay on at least basic, if not just staying with aero. If the looks of aero is your problem, I'm sure there are some themes on deviant art you might like. Just a little something extra with my answer.

Comment: I like the look of the classic theme, but it's not worth it to lose the other features.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use this DWM Theme which emulates the old ClassicTheme:

[**Classic AE**](http://saarineames.deviantart.com/art/Classic-AE-2-5-3-Final-343638171)

[image]

Comment: Requires use of a GPL Github hosted program UxStyle to enable the custom theme. Instructions referenced by that Deviantart page: http://www.sevenforums.com/themes-styles/141600-aero-theme-visually-similar-classic-theme.html#post3147400 (in addition the post also details how to enable additional XP-esque tweaks, such as adding the XP Quicklaunch toolbar)

Comment: Doesn't supports colour tweaking, but altogether looks like an amazing modded theme if you want to have your Aero Cake and let XP eat it too